# Pass extra variable to a function with predefined arguments like Array.Reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have a reducer function like this

```
let reducer = (acv, cv) => {
     return acv += cv;
}

function createMenus(arr){
    let someValue = getNewValue();
    arr.reduce(reducer, '');

    //I want to bind my above someValue to reducer function so, I can append it to my string like below
}

let reducer = (acv, cv, someValue) => {
     return acv += (cv+someValue);
}
```

I tried of doing something using `bind()` but not successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in your code to your advantage.

You can create a function that returns a function.

`createMenus` below takes one argument and uses the value passed to it, returning another function that will operate in the array's reduce function, so calling `reducer(someValue)` actually returns another function. That function is what is passed to reduce(in the same way you are doing it above).

```js
function getNewValue() {
  return 'foo';
}

function reducer(someValue) {
  return (acv, cv) => {
     return acv += (cv + someValue);
  }
};

function createMenus(arr){
    let someValue = getNewValue();
    return arr.reduce(reducer(someValue), '');
}

console.log(createMenus(['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

**UPDATE**

As @george mentioned in the coments, you could also use arrow functions to accomplish the same thing. The syntax is much shorter, but readability is in the eyes of the beholder.

`let reducer = value => (a, v) => a + (v + value);`

Even if you find it more readable, it is possible that you will make your code harder to debug utilizing this method as it can be harder to track down an error that occurs in an anonymous function than it is in a named function.

Comment: Your answer works best but I cannot understand one thing and I would be really grateful if you could explain how does (acv, cv) is getting values while we are passing only someValue to reducer function?

Comment: `let reducer = value => (a, v) => a + (v + value)` would look better.

Comment: @georg can you please explain how will (a,v) will get values while we pass only value to our reducer function?

Comment: @Airy: it's called a "closure", https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures. This `reducer` should be more accurately called `makeReducer`

Answer (score 1):

You can access `someValue` by defining `reducer` **inside** another function definition where `someValue` is available. (This is a use of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in JavaScript.)

```js
const
  myArr = ["big", "medium", "tiny"],
  myStr = createMenus(myArr);
console.log(myStr);

function createMenus(arr){
  const
    someValue = getNewValue(),
    reducer = (acv, cv) => acv + (cv + someValue),
    output = arr.reduce(reducer, '');
  return(output);
}
function getNewValue(){
  return "MenuItem, ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cat. That really helped specially knowing about Closures.